# Telegram API returns 0 length chats array

Tags: backend, telegram, mtproto

I'm trying to get my telegram groups using MTProto like this:

```
mtproto.call('users.getFullUser', {
    id: {
        _: "inputUserSelf"
    }
}).then(console.log);
```

All the data is valid but groups array is empty for some reason. 2FA is disabled.
Can somebody tell me how can I get the full chats list?

Tried a few accounts.